# OVER PARTITION BY SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have table with *owners,cars,price*. In single query (with usage of over and partition by) i need to get one column with share of value of car in all cars of owner(one owner can have multiple cars) and share of value of car in all cars. I did something like this

`price::decimal/sum(price)OVER(PARTITION BY owners.id),`

`price::decimal/sum(price)OVER(PARTITION BY SUM(price))`

First one is working perfectly, but i do not know how to do the second one. SUM is not working because we have to point out to column, but how to get summed value of all cars in this case?

I just have for instance 3 cars, every costs 10$. There are 2 owners A and B. A has 2 cars. So i need to get

- A's 1st car 50%(value of A's cars) 33%(value of all cars)
- A's 2nd car 50%(value of A's cars) 33%(value of all cars)
- B's 1st car 100%(value of B's cars) 33%(value of all cars)

Im just curious can i do it without any subquery, just only with Partition By

Comment: Please show us some data you start with and the result you expect to get ? Also please show us the whole query.

Comment: I just have for instance 3 cars, every costs 10$. There are 2 owners A and B. A has 2 cars. So i need to get ```A 1st car 50%(of A's cars) 33%(of all)|||A 2nd car 50%(of A's cars) 33%(of all)|| B 1st car 100%(of B's cars) 33%(of all)

Im just curious can i do it without any subquery, just only with Partition By

Comment: Please add this additional info in your question. You can update your question with edit button under the question. Also do not forget to add the code that works for you as you say: "First one is working perfectly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
select 
round((price::decimal/sum(price) over (partition by id)),4) * 100 || ' %' as share_of_owner
, round((price::decimal/sum(price) over()), 4) * 100 || ' %' as share_of_cars
from mytable
group by id, cars, price
```

[here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ed28961eb80b222f8080fb00f95746a5)

I have used `round` where I have rounded to 4 decimals. You can change that to your needs.

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) as easy as that!